# Looking for a regex to test for filenames with multiple extensions

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for regular expression to test for files with more than one extensions, i.e test.1.log.old

Thanks,
M.

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried so far?

Comment: @user735248, define what a successful test is... and what have you already tried?

Comment: We really need more specifics - such as the underlying filesystem. In many file systems (such as the Mac OS Extended partition on my computer) the text of this comment is actually a valid filename. Note my lack of commas or special characters.

Answer (score -1):

If you are only testing filenames, then this will work.

```
(.[^.]+\.){2}
```

You may need to modify the regex if you try to match against more than file names (path).

Comment: The first dot in your expresseion seems strange to me. With it, it will not match `a.b.c`.

Comment: @Jens - you are right.  The first dot should match for any character.  Please try this one `(.[^.]*\.){2}` - it seems to work for `a.b.c`